# comparing values between different rows of database and getting maximum count

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in which a row contains following data. So i need to compare data among themselves and show which data has maximum count.for ex. my table has following fruits name. So i need to compare these fruits among themselves and show max fruit count first.

```
s.no |             field1             |
1    |apple,orange,pineapple          |
2    |apple,pineapple,strawberry,grapes|
3    |apple,grapes,                   |
4    |orange,mango                    |
```

i.e apple comes first,grapes second,pineapple third and so on. and these datas are entered dynamically, so whatever the values is entered dynamically it needs to compare among themselves and get max count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run queries on column field 1, then why not consider `normalization` ? Otherwise it might keep on getting complex and dirty in future.

Your current table will look like this (for serianl number 1 only), Pk can be an autoincrement primary key.

```
Pk | s.no    |fruitId|
1  |   1     |1     |
2  |   1     |2     |
3  |   1     |3     |
```

Your New Table of Fruits

```
PK    |fruitName  |
1     |Apple      |
2     |Orange     |
3     |Pineapple  |
```

This also helps you to avoid redundancy.

Comment: but if the data are dynamic, then how to compare them..i dunno what data is going to entered next..so whatever the values is entered dynamically it needs to compare among themselves and get max count

Answer (score 2):

Great question.

This is a classical bad outcome of not having the data normalized.

I recommend you to read about [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), normalize your tables and see after that how easy it is to do this with simple SQL queries

Comment: k tudor..but if the data are dynamic, then how to compare them..i dunno what data is going to entered next..so whatever the values is entered dynamically it needs to compare among themselves and get max count

Comment: have a look at Zohaib answer - that is a very good start for normalizing the data - it also solves your 'problem'

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution would be counting the amount of fruits where you insert/update the row and add a `fruitCount` column. You can then use this column to order by.

Zohaib has to correct solution though - if you have the time and possibility for such changes. And I definitely suggest you to read Tudor's link!